# Creating a carousel in a small and wide container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://jsfiddle.net/8tcupybL/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Hello, world!</title>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ussettler.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sykesuss.css">
```

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="ussnav" class="col-12 col-md-12 nopadding">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/ussettler.png" id="logo"></a></li>
                <li></li>
                <li>Contact</li>
                <li>About</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="ussbody" class="col-12 col-md-12 nopadding container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="paneluss" class="col-9 col-md-9 nopadding container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="contactuss" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 nopadding container-fluid">

                        </div>
                        <div id="galleryuss" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 nopadding container-fluid">
                            <!--<div class="carousel">
                                <div>1<img src="images/ussettler"></div>
                                <div>2<img src="images/ussettler"></div>
                                <div>3<img src="images/ussettler"></div>
                                <div>4<img src="images/ussettler"></div>
                                <div>5<img src="images/ussettler"></div>
                                <div>6<img src="images/ussettler"></div>
                                <div>7<img src="images/ussettler"></div>
                            </div>-->
                        </div>
                        <div id="teaminfouss" class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 nopadding container-fluid">
                            <div id="infotext"><p>More introduction on service and team.</p></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="ussfooter" class="col-12 col-md-12 nopadding">
            <ul class="footerlist fixedfooter">
                <li>USSettler @ 2017</li>
                |
                <li>Disclaimer</li>
                |
                <li>Privacy Policy</li>
                |
                <li>Join Our Team</li>
                |
                <li>Contact Us</li>
                |
                <li> 
                    <span>Sign up for our updates</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/ussettler.js"></script>
```

In the fiddle above I am looking to add a reponsive image carousel to the middle section. There is an example in the mock image posted. I am new to carousel's and would prefer little to no javascript if possible. Or if anyone has a good link to where I can learn the html/css version or the javascript required to make one that would be awesome thanks!

[Mock Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkFfZ.png)

Comment: No one can help me?

Comment: using col-12 and col-md-12 fits the parent container. remove container-fluid class on the #contact, #gallery and #team and give a try

Comment: do you need something like this ?  https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/5yk0qm8g/1/